# Can I prepopulate an exposed filter text field?

Tags: views

I want to get some value from session and put it into one of the exposed filter text fields of my view as default. Later the user can change the value and filter again.

Is there any way to do it? My session variable will be taken with:

```
<?php return $_SESSION['ip_geoloc']['location']['city']; ?>
```

Comment: "My session variable will be taken with:"?

Comment: With what? is it a rebus?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question with the code...Actually it is not important. It can also be a simple variable