# How can I set default value (prepopulate) for field in views exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

I've tried to use solution from [Can I prepopulate an exposed filter text field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35504/can-i-prepopulate-an-exposed-filter-text-field) but failed. Cache clearing does not help.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "views_exposed_form" && $form['#id'] == "views-exposed-form-test-populate-page" ) {
    $form['title']['#default_value'] = 'test title';
    dpm($form);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out as below with **hook_views_pre_build**.

```
function module_views_pre_build(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
    if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {
        $view->display['page_1']->handler->handlers['filter']['title']->value = 'Test title';
    }
}
```

Replace 'page_1' with the correct display_id.

Comment: Well. It works. But it is too complex for me to understand. I hope there is more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dimetry. Since it is a drupal view you can add the default value in views itself. Please open your view and in the **Filter Criteria** section select the field you want to add the default value. It opens up a popup in that you can able to see "Value" field. Please give your default value there.

Please see the below picture for your reference.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I need more complex variant other than just fixed value. And I need to understand how to assign default value to the exposed filter by PHP code.

Comment: Try using **views_pre_build** to set the default value by php code.

Comment: I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551855/set-form-exposed-filter-default-value) without quick success. Well. I'll try to dig it more carefully.